# UITableViewController shows the same cell after updating to xcode 6

Tags: ios8, xcode6, custom-cell

My UITableViewController works not properly after updating xcode to version 6.

Im using custom cells in my tableview:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    BookDataTableViewCell * cell = (BookDataTableViewCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BookDataTableViewCell"];

    BookData * data = [_searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell setBookData:data];

    NSLog(@"BookDataTableViewController: cell pointer = %p", cell);

    return cell;
}

// BookDataTableViewCell.m
@interface BookDataTableViewCell()

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *      bookTitle;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *      bookAuthor;

@end

@implementation BookDataTableViewCell

    -(void)setBookData:(BookData *)bookData{

        _bookData = bookData;

        NSLog(@"BookDataTableViewCell: _bookTitle pointer = %p", _bookTitle);
        NSLog(@"BookDataTableViewCell: bookTitle = %@", _bookData.title); // allways different!!!

        [[self bookTitle] setText:_bookData.title];
        [[self bookAuthor] setText:_bookData.author];
    }
}
```

After updating xcode to version 6 all controller cells show the same book info **using the last BookData in _searchResult list**, although the data passed to BookDataTableViewCell are allways different.

Yesterday, befor update, the controller worked as expected...

Some idea what might have gone wrong?

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer to this? I think I'm having a similar problem with a custom cell and a uitableview. I have a button that causes an update to the text in a label. Works great in xcode 5, but in xcode 6 the pointer seems to no longer point to the label on the screen.

Comment: @raphael i had to define my labels again (drag and drop). you can also try to clean your project.